# How do I convert hex file to binary array Android, Java

Tags: java, android, io

I want to convert chars symbols from .hex file to byte array. I am using this code but the result is not the same symbol from my file.

My code:

```
    public byte[] getResource(int id, Context context) throws IOException {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    InputStream is = resources.openRawResource(id);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[2 * 1024 * 1024];
    byte[] data;

    try {
        int read;
        do {
            read = is.read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.length);
            if (read == -1) {

                break;


            }
            String hex = new String(readBuffer);
            data = hexStringToByteArray(hex);
            bout.write(data);
            //   bout.write(readBuffer, 0, read);
        } while (true);

        return bout.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}

public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

First 3 lines from my .hex file

> :020000040800F2
>   :20000000103C0020650200081502000817020008190200081B0200081D0200080000000056
>   :200020000000000000000000000000001F020008210200080000000023020008714A00087C

But when I check resulting array, I see this:
 -16, 32, 0, 0, 64, -128, 15, 31, -17, 32, 0, 0, 0, 16, 60, 0, 32, 101, 2, 0, 8, 21...

Where is my mistake? Show me right way please!

Comment: If you've got a *text* file, you should be reading that line-by-line as text, with a `Reader`. Note how each line of your file apparently starts with a colon, but you'll currently be treating that as a hex digit.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for your comment, but can you explain a bit more please

Comment: Well your code is reading the file as if it's a binary file, reading from an `InputStream` and manually converting the bytes to strings. Your file appears to be organized in lines, so why aren't you reading it line by line with a `BufferedReader`? Then you need to trim the colon from each line...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First read all data from file and remove all incorrect symbols such(':') from string as @pitfall says and store in string then do following thing.

```
String s="yourStringFromFile";
byte[] b = new BigInteger(s,16).toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove all incorrect symbols (such ':') from hex string.

hexStringToByteArray(":020000040800F") -> [-16, 32, 0, 0, 64, -128, 15]
hexStringToByteArray("020000040800F2") -> [2, 0, 0, 4, 8, 0, -14]